# How do I restrict certain sites in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, blocking, restrictions

Is there a way to restrict access from certain sites so that IE can't access ? I would like a solution that doesn't need installing a third party program to do so.

Either something in IE or some Windows configs (like hosts files or something) ?

I do not care if it is very easy to bypass the restriction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Internet Explorer has a feature like this built in and has for a long time.  Find the "Internet Options" menu item (under the "Tools" menu in IE 7 & 8).  From the dialog that opens select the "Content" tab.

From the content tab, enable the "Content Advisor" and select "Settings."  From the settings page select the "Approved Sites" tab.  Type the URL you are looking for and click "Never" to block the site.

Comment: This does not block access to the sites in the "Restricted sites". What it does is augment the security settings for those sites. ie: blocking javascripts, dynamic content, etc. You can still access the sites in the Restricted Sites, unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You're right... got ahead of myself.  Updated.