# How to allow to access only a list of certain sites in IE

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-explorer-8, restrictions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restrict certains sites in IE ?](https://superuser.com/questions/261792/how-do-i-restrict-certains-sites-in-ie)

I have a few tens of laptops and I need to restrict the Internet access on those laptops and allow only a few certain sites. I know I can do it using Content advisor in IE but manually it will take a lot of time.

Is there any way to do it using some script or something else to speed up the process?

Comment: CA is the is the only practical way to do this AFAIK, without using code.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, it is exact opposite of that question, read both more carefully and open my question please!

Comment: Both questions have the same answer, use CA. All other methods will take a greater amount of time which is what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: @Studiohack, this is not an exact duplicate. The answer is CA in both cases, but really only partially so for this. Burja adds the situation of having multiple machines he wishes to apply this on, and so the answer must include that additional information.

Answer (score 2):

Can you set up Content Advisor in the IE Admin Kit, lockdown all settings, and then just run the created installer package on each computer?

UPDATE (from comment below):
Download the IE Admin Kit here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb407001-7f6e-4ca1-8583-e91e69e872dd

It's pretty easy to use. Just download and install it and it'll walk you through all the various possible customizations for IE8. If you have IE8 installed on your computer already, you can even import the settings (such as the Content Advisor settings) you've already set there.

With this kit you can create either a full install of IE8 or just a setting patch installer that contains only the changes you've made, depending on whether or not IE is already installed on each target computer.

The kit is used by IT departments and anybody else who needs to create a standardized installation of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Do you mean reinstall IE on every laptop? I'm not sure if it will be quicker, bearing in mind the time I will spend on figuring out how to use IE Admin Kit (have no idea what it is).

Comment: Download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb407001-7f6e-4ca1-8583-e91e69e872dd

It's pretty easy to use. Just download and run it and it'll walk you through all the various possible customizations for IE8. If you have IE8 installed on your computer already, you can even import the settings you've already set there.

You can create either a full install or just a setting patch, depending on whether or not IE is already installed on each target computer.